# ordinal logistic regression with multicollinearity among the independent continuous variables

Tags: regression, logistic, multicollinearity, ordinal-data

I have an ordinal dependent variable, named A (small, medium, big) and independent continuous variables (C, C1, C2 and C3) highly correlated between each other. For example the sum of the variables C1, C2 and C3 is equal to variable C. Also, when C1 increases, either C2 or C3 will decrease or vice versa.

Can I perform an ordinal logistic regression analysis in the former data in order to obtain the relationship between D and C1, C2, C3, C? And how should I deal with multicollinearity among the independent variables?

Comment: You first need to determine whether multicollinearity is a problem.  It would help to have more information about your situation, such as statistics describing the degree of multicollinearity and sample sizes.

Comment: If the sum of the predictors is a constant as you state, then just remove one of them.